# AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway: How to send a binary file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function which fetches a file from s3 using the input key in event and needs to send the same to client. I am using the following function to get the file from s3

```
function getObject(key){
  var params = {
    Bucket: "my_bucket",
    Key: key   
  }
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data.Body)
    })
  })
}
```

If I send the response of this promise (buffer) to `context.succeed`, it is displayed as a JSON array on front end. How can I send it as a file ? The files can be either ZIP or HTTP Archive (HAR) files. The s3 keys contain the appropriate extension. I am guessing it has got something to do with the "Integration Response" in API Gateway. But not able to figure out where to change

Comment: Read the official AWS response in this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=195218

Comment: API Gateway team - Mark B is right, that is the official status. We are working to support binary passthrough in the future, but no ETA.

Comment: is there any workaround for this. Our complete application is serverless. We would want to avoid creating a separate EC2 instance for just download purpose

Comment: You could generate a pre-signed S3 URL in your Lambda which your client uses to download.

Answer (score 4):

Good news, you can now handle binary input and output for API Gateway ([announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/) and [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html)).

Basically, nothing changes in your Lambda Function, but you can now set the `contentHandling` API Gateway Integration property to `CONVERT_TO_BINARY`.

Unfortunately, the official AWS examples showcase only the HTTP API Gateway backend, as the AWS Lambda support seems not complete yet. For example, I haven't managed to return gzipped content from AWS Lambda yet, although it should be possible thanks to the new binary support and the `$util.base64Decode()` mapping utility.

Comment: Could You please provide some examples? I am absolute beginner with AWS and I'm currently trying to upload zip file to Lambda and I would like also to do it locally using serverless and serverless-offline frameworks (for development)